# Does two way ANOVA excludes depending of one of the factors?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, t-test

I am not statistician so I am sorry if my question formulation sounds confusing.

The ultimate goal is to comapre two methods (A and B). Each method creates 24 numbers (so, 24 pairs). Apart from the method A and B, each of these numbers are linked to the same object. Something like this:

```
  Protein|structure|Method A  |Method B
    
  MDM2     a1       23          19
  MDM2     a2       25          8
  MDM2     a3       45          37
  P53      b1       19          18 
  P53      b2       ...         ...
  P53      b3
  XXX      c1
  XXX      c2
  XXX      c3
  YYY      d1
  YYY      d2
  YYY      d3
```

Ultimate goal is to compare method A to method B and determine whether one method has statistically significant difference to the other.

However, in my case comparison should be considered as pairwise within the Protein (MDM2 for example). So, I should not compare it as `a1A to a1B`; `a2A to a2B`.... It should more likely be pairwise within a protein: `a1A to a1a2a3B`; `a2A to a1a2a3B`;  `a3A a1a2a3B`. Then, `b1A to b1b2b3B`.

So ultimately, statistical methods tells me whether method A is statistically different than method B across entire sample. So that, at the end, if I "shuffle" the numbers within each method, but within Protein, I get same result.

Should I just create new, pairwise sample and do simple 2-sample t-test?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Pitouille, thanks for your time reading my question. My field is computational chemistry/drug design. I am not sure whether two-way ANOVA is the best way to go, I only have one comparison between method A and method B, however, important thing here is to eliminate dependency of the "Protein (aaa;bbb;ccc)". So that if I shuffle the numbers within the method A itself and do the same with method B, I would always get the same  statistics? Bcs currently I am comparing a1A to a1B; but in reality it can also be a1A to a2B; a1A to A3B (pairwise).

Comment: So instead of doing pairwise comparison, I am thinking whether two-way ANOVA can help elimination of dependency of "Protein" aaa;bbb;ccc;ddd;eee;fff;ggg.

Comment: Sorry... I deleted my comment because I am not sure to understand your data...! So, this is not paired data... you want to analyze the 2 methods and the protein does not actually matter... is that right?

Comment: @Pitouille This is exactly what I want :) Sorry if my formulation was not clear enough

Comment: Is it continous data that you are collecting?

Comment: Yes, the data was obtained and measured by some method. It is continuous and not discrete data if my understanding allows to comment :)

Comment: Thanks! In this case, I believe you need a 2 sample t-test... What is your ultimate goal? Do the samples have the same size?

Comment: Samples have the same size. Can I ask you if its possible now that I think about it in detail: ultimate goal is to compare method A to method B. However, there is a reason why there is a1,a2,a3 and not b1,b2,b3. Is it possible to compare method A to method B over entire sample (24 pairs);but not to exclude absolute dependency of protein.  In a sense. let statistical test know, that these numbers actually come from a1a2a3 and not from b1b2b3? However, statistical test should not compare them as a1A to a1B; a2A to a2B, it should consider them as pairwise comparison within each letter (a, b, c)

Comment: before you answer I will reformulate the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, it seems that you want to compare the means of two populations (continuous data, sample size n=24) and determine whether they differ. Therefore, your hypothesis could be stated as below:

$H_0:$ The means for the 2 populations are equal

$H_a:$ The means for the 2 populations are not equal

If you want to compare both method independently of the protein, a 2-sample t-test will do the work assuming that t-test requirements are met (random sample, independent groups...). In R, using `t.test`, you can specify if it concerns paired test, equal or unequal variance...

Now if you want to compare methods within each subgroup (a, b, c), t-test will no longer work, so ANOVA could be an option. However, you might face a challenge since I do not think your data will meet the minimum requirement in terms of sample size (my understanding is that your original sample size is 24... so, I supposed it will at least less than 8 since you mentioned a minimum of 3 groups).

Comment: Thanks a lot for for your suggestions and taking a time to propose ways based on your knowledge and experience. I am thinking of doing something like: taking the mean of a1a2a3 for each protein (with providing standard deviation) and doing 2-sample t-test because it is a random sample and two groups are independent. Thanks a lot!